# ADB not responding. You can wait more, or kill "adb.exe" ... windows 8

Tags: android, windows-8, adb

When I try to test my Android application with an android emulator as always I now suddenly get an error message. I'm working with Windows 8. So far I tried the following things which unfortunately could not solve the problem:

- reinstalling eclipse with android adt
- reinstalling java
- installing "android studios" first solved the problem but after one day mysteriously also here adb, stopped working with the error message given in the title " ADB not responding ...

furthermore I unsuccessfully tried out some advice from Mr. Google:

- Stopping adb.exe via task-manager and restarting eclipse / android studios
- "adb kill-server" then "start-server" via command prompt
- setting the path to adb.exe as an environment variable
- switching off any antivirus or firewall
- starting the IDEs as an administrator
- updating the IDEs

The only thing I can remember doing which may have destroyed adb on my computer for all times: I connected my motorola smartphone to my laptop and installed the motorola usb drivers but as I said the adb also won't work with the emulator.

Any help would be kindly appreciated. The issue bothers me for more than an entire day now. Maybe someone had similar problems on Windows 8 ?

Comment: You could go and try to delete the motorola driver if you've got the idea that is the one messing things up

Comment: The only thing I found was an "ADB Interface" in the windows device manager. I deleted it. No effect.

Comment: As I said: I already got the problem when using Eclipse with Android ADT before I installed any motorola drivers. Seems more that anyhow the IDE cannot really find the adb.exe, altough this normally works after a standard installation. But neither in "Eclipse" nor in "Android Studios" I can find any ADB settings in order to repair / change it.

Comment: This still happens on Ubuntu, so not related to Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meanwhile the emulator is working again. I cannot definetly say what solved the problem. What It could be a combination of two things:

- Deleting the hidden ".android" folder under C:\Users...
  (Probably there was some malfunctioning automatically created code)
- Deleting and recreating the Path variable to the folder with adb.exe ( ...\sdk\platform-tools\;)

Finally it could be a Windows 8 issue which I don't understand.

Comment: I found issues without making changes to both a windows 8 and windows 7 machine. Definitely something with Windows. I wonder if anyone has tried on MAC or Linux?

Comment: Not related to Windows, this happens in Ubuntu 13.10 as of March 2014, for my whole team...

Comment: I have this issue with linux

Comment: Deleting de .android folder worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Simply deleting the ".android" folder worked. My hero

Answer (score 16):

On OSX helped:

- Close Android Studio
- Kill all processess using 5037 port

  `sudo lsof -i |grep 5037`

  `sudo kill PID_NUMBER`
- Run adb devices from console

  `adb devices`

Comment: +1. Nice. This is the only thing that worked for me. I even tried OS reset.

Comment: Worked for me. Just another tip: if the Android SDK is not on the PATH variable, you can find adb on <sdk>/platform-tools

Comment: Help me under Windows 7 too - didn't even have to close Android Studio. I just killed the adb process and ran "adb devices". Thanks.

Comment: This worked on Mac. I was trying to run with Xamarin but was getting  errors.

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

Open a command prompt with administration permission and type

> netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled

This worked for me

Edit: Windows only

Answer (score 3):

Kill the adb.exe with a command prompt. Open a command prompt were your adb.exe is located and type
adb kill-server

Comment: I did that too. No effect.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `HTTP Proxy` blocked the localhost `127.0.0.1:5037`
If you have config the `HTTP Proxy`, make sure to exclude the localhost like picture below

Also, port can also be blocked by the firewall and anti-virus firewall, please notice as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1. at the prompt try `adb kill-server`
2. Start one of your AVDs
3. at the prompt try `adb root`

The prompt should say `adbd is already running as root`.

That should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. Killing server and starting it didn't but `adb root` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone else, for me the problem was related with the USB hub that the tablet was plugged into on the computer (unplugging the webcam which was in use fixed it).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. Don't worry. I have an solution. Go to Task Manager. Kill the process called adb.exe. You will find 2 or 3 processes. Kill all of them. You are done. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problems. Verify port 5037 is free and ports 5555 to 5585 are available and never used by another process.

"ADB server sets up connections to all running emulator/device instances. It locates emulator/device instances by scanning odd-numbered ports in the range 5555 to 5585"

FROM: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

To find out which process is listening on a port on Windows yo can use:

C:> netstat -an -o

FROM: [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

Comment: svchost is used port 5037. I killed so I am able to run adb devices. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, here is my simple fix:

-Go to **task manager** in windows, look for **adb.exe**, and kill it

-Go to command prompt, and tap **adb devices** ==> it will automaticaly start adb daemon

Answer (score 0):

I finally just restarted the computer, and that solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall HTC Sync. Or disable it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to open `adb` from command prompt from directory location as `<sdk>\platform-tools`,
- If adb file is missing try to re-install Android SDK with latest version,
  And try to run again..

I think issues will solved, by this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on a Mac OS X.

I shut down Android Studio and ran `adb get-state` in the terminal. When I started Android Studio back up, the warning had gone away.

BTW, I did just try restarting Android Studio without any luck. I am sure a restart of OS would have fixed it too.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing with the Asus Sync utility (with the both our Transformer's 700 and 701).
I think there is a USB-port conflict between ABD driver and Sync utility.

Exit from Sync utility resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this could be caused by a bunch of different issues. This just happened to me because I had my android phone device plugged in for USB debugging, then after a few hours (and multiple android studio/phpstorm restarts) I had to do unplug the device manually. Things started working again after unplugging.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem few days ago. When I opened my task manager it showing me two adb runnig. It may be because of I am using mobogenie for connecting my android phone for debugging application. This problem is because of moboginie and adt port conflict. then I have followed following procedure to sort out this issue.

!) close eclipse
2) Go to task manager and kill all adb processes.
3) Now go to platform-tools in android sdk
4)press shift+right click mouse and select "open command window here" option
5) type

adb kill-server
adb start-server

6)if server sucessfully started then start eclipse and then connect your phone
(Remember dont connect your phone before starting eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me every time:
go to File->Invalidate Caches/Restart
      select **Invalidate and Restart**

And, You are good to go.