# ADB not responding

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04

I am using android-studio in ubuntu.I am new to android programming.During installation itself I have received a message as "stopping ADB server failed".But remaining packages have been installed successfully.But when I try to run my first program it showed me as

"ADB not responding. if you'd like to retry then please manually kill adb and click 'restart'"

I have tried adb kill-server" but it showed me as command not found.

What shoul I do fix this bug?

And also I want include that I am not running ./studio.sh in root mode.Will this may be the reason for the above problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790421/adb-kill-server-not-responding?rq=1

Comment: http://simpledeveloper.com/adb-not-responding-android-solution/

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have followed the links but it is showing me these two errors   "Error:Error: Cannot run program "/home/sowmya/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory",   "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /home/sowmya/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloWorld/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/sowmya/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory"           What should I do now?

Comment: Install this sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32z1-dev lib32stdc++6  package

Comment: https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/adb-is-not-responding-you-can-wait-more-or-kill-adbexe-process-manually-and-click-restart

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851480/adb-not-responding-you-can-wait-more-or-kill-adb-exe-windows-8

Comment: http://simpledeveloper.com/adb-not-responding-android-solution/

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thank you so much.Finally I ran my first app.

Comment: can you tell me how to solved this ?

Comment: I have installed those above mentioned packages.Then I executed my first app.But it showed me to enable kvm.Then I have installed kvm.Now it's perfectly good and it is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows: Add a system variable as following and then restart your Computer then try again - it will be OK

```
ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT
10501
```

[image: system Variable]